# How to analyze an unbalanced within-subject ANOVA design?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, missing-data, unbalanced-classes

I have data from an experiment involving 4 groups of subjects, 2 possible interventions first and 3 possible intervention at a 2nd point, repeated data measurements from each subjects multiple time points with a decreasing number of measurements at each progressive time points after 2nd intervention (this was planned). My problem is that I am not sure how to analyze unbalanced data.

More specifically, my experiment involves the following groups & interventions:

1. Control group (no 1st treatment, no 2nd treatment)
2. Experimental group 1 (1st treatment, no 2nd treatment)
3. Experimental group 2 (1st treatment, type A 2nd treatment)
4. Experimental group 3 (1st treatment, type B 2nd treatment)

The 1st treatment is the same for all subjects that received it. All the groups started out with an equal number of subjects (24 subjects) in each group (for a grand total of 96 subjects in the study).

Samples were taken from the subjects at the following different time points to measure one dependent variable:

- `t(0)` - Baseline AKA prior to time of the 1st treatment (or equivalent time) for ALL subjects (96 total subjects, so `96 total data points`)
- `t(1)` - x number of weeks after the 1st treatment & prior to the 2nd treatment (or equivalent time) for ALL subjects (96 total subjects, so `96 total data points`)
- `t(2)` - x number of weeks after the 2nd treatment (or equivalent time) for ALL subjects (96 total subjects, so `96 total data points`). 1/4 of the subjects from each group (6 subjects from each group, 24 subjects total) have the treatment site removed for analysis.
- `t(3)` - y number of weeks after the 2nd treatment (or equivalent time) for remaining 3/4 of subjects (72 total subjects, so `72 total data points`). Additional 1/4 of the subjects from each group (6 subjects from each group, 24 subjects total) have the treatment site removed for analysis.
- `t(4)` - z number of weeks after the 2nd treatment (or equivalent time) for remaining 2/4 of subjects (48 total subjects, so `48 total data points`). Additional 1/4 of the original number of subjects from each group (6 subjects from each group, 24 subjects total) .
- `t(5)` - zz number of weeks after the 2nd treatment (or equivalent time) for remaining 1/4 of subjects (24 total subjects, so `24 total data points`). All the remaining subjects from each group have the treatment site removed for analysis.

(I hope all that makes sense.)

I am trying to analyze whether the 1st treatment has the effect we expect on the subjects, and whether the 2nd treatment has any further effects. Unfortunately, we *need* to remove the treatment site after each timepoint `t(2)`-`t(5)` in order to obtain the microscopic data see what, if anything, is changing. The treatment area is quite small, so taking a portion of it is really not an option.

Since I have 1 dependent variable to measure, 3 treatment variables, and don't have any random variables in my study, I am assuming I should use repeated measures fixed effect ANOVA. However, given I have progressively fewer data points (but equal among groups) for the last 3 time points (AKA starting with 96 @ `t(2)` --> 72 @ `t(3)` --> 48 @ `t(4)` --> 24 @ `t(5)`), I am unsure how I should even start doing the analysis or what program would work for me. I have GraphPad Prism, but it only lets me go up to Two-way ANOVA, and I am unsure if I need to use 3-way ANOVA or not, or even if I need to use a different method.

Suggestions on how to analyze the data and what program, if any, would be very helpful. Any other insights or suggestions are also welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to our site and +1 for your question. I have reformatted it slightly using [Markdown syntax](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help), which you can use if you want to update your question or post new ones in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for reformatting it for me. I really appreciate it and updated my question using your suggestions.<br/>
I enlisted in the help of another researcher, and we tried using Excel with the DDXL Add-in, but we encountered the same limitation GraphPad had with only being able to go up to 2-way ANOVA. She also said she thought I would need to use 4-way ANOVA because she feels I have 4 treatment variables, not 3. I still don't see it that way/why she feels there are 4, not 3 treatment variables. I was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on which is correct?